# Do check rides completed by part 141 schools with self-examining authority count like normal check rides for CFI renewal and gold seal?

Tags: faa, cfi, checkride

Some schools have self-examining authority issued by the FAA.

Do check rides completed in this manner count the same way as a standard check ride for the purpose of CFI renewal and gold seal applications?

Comment: I don't have a reference but I am sure the answer would be YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which FSDO you ask.

I know that the Will Rogers FSDO in Oklahoma City says they do not, but the FSDO in Wichita, Kansas says they do and will take actions on applications accordingly.

Comment: Would you please define what "self examining authority" does allow a flight school to do so that we can learn from this?

Comment: @Michael Hall it would be best to make a new question about that specifically m

Comment: Never mind, a quick Google search answered my question.  P.S.  Have you ever entered an Ernest Hemmingway look-alike contest?  I think you would do well...  ;)